# SSRS 2008 Report Builder 3.0: Using CASE and WHEN Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0, case-when

I have my program set up to allow the user to select a station, then pick between 2 dates, then they pick what shift they want. They can pick Both, First, or Second. First is 6:00AM - 4:00PM and Second is 4:00PM - 3:00AM. I have 4 parameters in total. I think my program returns no values for second shift because not all values between 16 and 3 are greater then start and less then end. For example 6:00PM is not less than end hour of 3 so it is not included in output. How do I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @StartHour INT
DECLARE @EndHour INT
SET @StartHour = CASE @TimeRange 

WHEN 0 THEN 0 --Start of Overall--
WHEN 1 THEN 6 --1st Shif Start--
WHEN 2 THEN 16 --2nd Shift Start--
END

SET @EndHour = CASE @TimeRange   
WHEN 0 THEN 24 --End of Overall--
WHEN 1 THEN 16 --End of First Shift--
WHEN 2 THEN 3 --End of Second Shift--
END

SELECT
Testerline1_CycleTimes.Station,
Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry

WHERE
Testerline1_CycleTimes.Station LIKE @Station
AND Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry Between @Start And @End
AND DATEPART( hh , Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry ) >= @StartHour
AND DATEPART( hh , Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry ) < @EndHour
```

Comment: I don't see the problem here, and I don't see a valid SQL Script either. What's the `WHERE` clause for? You have two variables, how can they be display in the wrong order?

Comment: I only copied the code that relates to my problem. It is T-SQL code being used in Report Builder, not sure if that makes a difference. When I have my code like this it does not return values for Case 2, which should be 4:00PM to 3:00AM.

Comment: It's hard to figure out the problem without more detail. Perhaps setup a SQL Fiddle with test data and whole query?

Comment: if you are considering only `hours` part where is `day` part. Meaning if 4PM day and 3 AM day are both different how this is handled.

Comment: Let me edit my original question and include more code

Comment: what is `@Start` & `@End` ???

Comment: They are 2 datetime parameters chosen by the user in a calender picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed to answer the last day, but still if you haven't solved the issue. I would suggest to give a try using union for your second shift data. As the day change in selecting between time range

```
/*******************************************************
   --Commented Code
    DECLARE @StartHour INT
    DECLARE @EndHour INT
    SET @StartHour = CASE @TimeRange 

    WHEN 0 THEN 0 --Start of Overall--
    WHEN 1 THEN 6 --1st Shif Start--
    WHEN 2 THEN 16 --2nd Shift Start--
    END

    SET @EndHour = CASE @TimeRange   
    WHEN 0 THEN 24 --End of Overall--
    WHEN 1 THEN 16 --End of First Shift--
    WHEN 2 THEN 3 --End of Second Shift--
   END 
  *******************************************/

 If(@TimeRange=1)
 BEGIN
 SELECT
    Testerline1_CycleTimes.Station,
    Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry
 WHERE
    sterline1_CycleTimes.Station LIKE @Station
    AND Testerline_CycleTimes.StationEntry Between @Start And @End
    AND DATEPART( hh , Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry ) >= 6
    AND DATEPART( hh , Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry ) < 16
END

ELSE IF(@TimeRange=2)
BEGIN
SELECT
   Testerline1_CycleTimes.Station,
   Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry  
 WHERE
    Testerline1_CycleTimes.Station LIKE @Station
    AND Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry Between @Start And @End
    AND DATEPART( hh , Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry ) >= 16
UNION ALL
SELECT
     Testerline1_CycleTimes.Station,
     Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry
WHERE
    Testerline1_CycleTimes.Station LIKE @Station
    AND Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry Between @Start And @End
    AND DATEPART( hh , Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry ) < 3
END

 ELSE
 BEGIN
 SELECT
      Testerline1_CycleTimes.Station,
      Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry
 WHERE
     Testerline1_CycleTimes.Station LIKE @Station
     AND Testerline1_CycleTimes.StationEntry Between @Start And @End
 END
```

Comment: worked perfectly! Thank you so much I have been trying to solve this for 2 weeks!

Comment: This worked for second shift, but then it made my first shift values completely wrong. I cannot even find a pattern in the outputted values.

Comment: Although the real question refers to doubt in retrieving second shift data which i tried to explain through `union` but you can't use same query to retrieve the other results hence use conditional statements for the same. Updated my answer for same. Let me know if you still face any issues.